# Adding a class to code blocks generated by knitr

Tags: css, r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

When I knit my R markdown file to HTML via [the RWordPress package](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/), the formatting of the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags is disrupted because of other styling/plugins (I think [Crayon syntax highlighter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/) is the biggest culprit, but I'm not willing to part with it). One simple solution might be to add a class to every `<pre>` and `<code>` tag generated by Knitr, so that they can be styled separately with some CSS, but I can't determine an easy way to do this. Do any Knitr experts know how this could be done automagically? Other solutions are welcome if they are similarly simple.

EDIT: To possibly clarify, I *think* that what I need to be doing is overriding the default 'source' hook generated by `render_html()` and add a new tag that way, but I'm struggling to figure out how by reading [the documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks) or [the examples](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples).

Comment: I think i got your issue.. but still little unclear. cant you provide a sample code or fiddle.. ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery inside your Rmd document (which will be rendered to HTML) to add a class to every source code chunk:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('pre.r').addClass('yourClass');
});
</script>
```

This snippet adds the CSS class `.yourClass` to every `<pre>` element that already carries the class `.r`.

If you want to modify the `<code>` child of those elements use

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('pre, .r').children('code').addClass('yourClass');
});
</script>
```

From here on it is up to you how you style your `yourClass` code chunks with CSS.

Comment: Not what you wanted?